# Parsing three-digit years using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am seeing a strange issue parsing date-time strings with dates containing three-digit years with Python 3.x. Here's an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
dt = datetime.strptime('0699-02-02T15:11:43Z', format)
print(dt) # datetime.datetime(699, 2, 2, 15, 11, 43)
print(dt.strftime(format)) # '699-02-02T15:11:43Z'
print(datetime.strptime(dt.strftime(format), format))
```

I expected this to output `datetime.datetime(699, 2, 2, 15, 11, 43)`, but it produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '699-02-02T15:11:43Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), using `%Y` should produce a padded four-digit year, but this is not the output of `strftime`. Moreover, the output that I do get cannot be parsed back to the original `datetime` as the error above shows.

What could I be missing?

**Version:**
I am running via the `python:3.8` Docker image, but I have also tried `python:3.6` and `python:3.10`.

Comment: What OS/version of python are you running? It works fine on mine (Win10/Py3.8)

Comment: I am running `3.8.3` using the `python:3.8` Docker image.

Comment: Are you sure? Your outputs say `/usr/lib/python3.6`.

Comment: I've tried both, but yes, I should update the above output to match the version.

Comment: Seems like [an open Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue13305).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's a [reported bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue13305) on Python.

I'm using Python 3.10 on Windows and the output works as expected:

```
>> print(datetime.strptime(dt.strftime(format), format))
0699-02-02 15:11:43
```

A possible solution (hack): add the missing leading zeros to your string:

```
my_date = dt.strftime(format)
my_date = my_date.zfill(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the bug reference. Perhaps it's fixed on Windows in Python 3.10. `python:3.10` Docker image still has this error. Haven't tried 3.10 directly on Ubuntu or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the bug reference and the workaround. It does break with years of 5+ digits (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ but I can work around that too, just not so elegantly.